# Print list, with values from another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

Sorry if the question is worded awkwardly. What I'm tyring to do:

I have a list.

```
standardpizzalist = ["1. Supreme", "2. Godfather", "3. Meatlovers", "4. Capricosa", "5. BBQ Chicken", "6. Prawn Delight", "7. Basil and Pork",]
```

The customer has this list displayed, they then enter which selections they want, eg. 1, 3, 5 would represent Supreme, Meatlovers and BBQ Chicken. 
These values are saved in a list also:

```
orderedpizzas = [1, 3, 5]
```

I need the list orderedpizzas to be displayed on screen, but instead of 1, 3 and 5 being printed, I need it to read the values from the other list.
eg.  1. Supreme, 3. Meatlovers, 5. BBQ Chicken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
>>> for pizza in orderedpizzas: print standardpizzalist[pizza-1]

1. Supreme
3. Meatlovers
5. BBQ Chicken
```

Comment: perfect! I think this answers my question exactly! Will vote correct soon.

Comment: Awesome! I even simplified it to a one-liner ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off using a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead:

```
>>> pizza_dict
{1: 'Supreme', 2: 'Godfather', 3: 'Meatlovers', 4: 'Capricosa', 5: 'BBQ Chicken', 6: 'Prawn Delight', 7: 'Basil and Pork'}
>>> pizza_dict[1]
'Supreme'
>>> pizza_dict[3]
'Meatlovers'
>>> pizza_dict[5]
'BBQ Chicken'
```

And then we can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the names:

```
>>> ordered_pizzas = [1,3,5]
>>> names = [pizza_dict[num] for num in ordered_pizzas]
>>> names
['Supreme', 'Meatlovers', 'BBQ Chicken']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ', '.join(standardpizzalist[x-1] for x in orderedpizzas)
```

Will give you a comma separated list of ordered pizzas.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ordered dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

pizzas = OrderedDict()
pizzas[1] = 'Supreme'
pizzas[2] = 'Godfather'
...etc...
```

So then when you iterate over the items, the ordering is kept(unlike a regular dict):

```
for index, pizza in pizzas.items():
    print pizza      # First prints 'Supreme', then 'Godfather', etc...
```